# FGETC library name in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fgetc

Is there a library that I can explicitly link to my Fortran code to find FGETC function? I'm getting linker errors for unresolved external symbol for the fgetc function and I tried using 'USE IFPORT' but that broke a bunch of other stuff. I am building in Visual Studio 2008 and using Intel Fortran Composer XE 2011 compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `FGETC` is a non-standard function which Intel packages in the `IFPORT` module I'm not sure you have any alternative to use-associating it.  If use-associating the whole module causes problems, you might get away with

```
use ifport, only : fgetc
```